# Cannot load existing project on android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting this error whenever I try to load an existing project on android studio.

[image]

Comment: what error ?? what code is giving error, hard to give ansers without basic details

Comment: I have attached the image. Click on the "image".

Comment: What version of android studio are you using?
what version was the project built in?
have you tried reinstalling android studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ant in that project check the jdk version and add Java 8 as default and create a script called ant which sets the environment variable to the Java 6 JDK and then call the real ant (if you use ant in that project).